# Translating comparison operators into logic

Tags: logic, logic-translation

I have $P: x > 30$; $Q: x < 20$

Write simply as you can:

a) $P \land  Q$

My answer: $x > 30 \;and \; x < 20$

Which is always false:

So if I write: $30 < x < 20$ is it still correct?

b) $\lnot Q \; \land \; P$

My answer: $x \ge 20 \; and \; x > 30$

So: $ 20 \le x > 30$ is it correct?

---

Another example:

$P: x < 30; \; Q: x > 20$

a) $P \land Q$

My answer: $ x < 30 \; and \; x > 20$

Therefore: $20 < x < 30 $

Comment: The first one is correct, but peculiar.  The second one is not correct: nobody ever writes $20\le x > 30$, so it has no well-understood meaning.  There is a better solution for the second one; you need to think about it more thoroughly.

Comment: @MJD The second one then I suppose is: $x > 30$

Comment: I edited the question with one more example.

Comment: I think it would be clearer if I change the first one: $x > 30 \;and \; x < 20$ with $20 > x  > 30$

Comment: But usually writing a pair of inequalities as a compound inequality (e.g., $1 < x < 2$) is reserved for pairs of inequalities that are actually compatible (that is, have a solution). That's what makes it peculiar.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, the answer is not well-defined because it depends on what symbols you're allowed to use. As you note, for any real $x$, "$P \land Q$" is always false, and hence equivalent to "$\bot$", which denotes "contradiction".

For the second one, as you noted in a comment, for any real $x$ "$\neg Q \land P$" is equivalent to "$x > 30$", so that's the simplest.

For the third one, yes, "$20 < x < 30$" is the simplest way that we can write it. In general we use such notation to express a chain of equalities or inequalities.